# Создание csv-файла Python

Tags: python

Необходимо создать csv-файл с Header.

При добавлении нового товара, в случае если у него в словаре есть header, которого нет в csv, то нужно добавить этоn header в csv, и всем продуктам, которые были до добавления оставить это место пустое.

Как это можно реализовать? Возможно сначала можно это хранить в какой-то временной структуре, и только на последнем шаге сохранить в csv.

До этого создавал только csv с фиксированным количеством столбцов, но с динамическими никогда не работал

Пример:

```
{'NAME': 'AquaDoctor C-60 50 кг. в гранулах', 
'PRICE': '17\xa0919,00', 
'STOCK_STATUS': False, 
'SKU': '1551', 
'CATEGORY_ID': 28, 
'IMAGE': 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/c/6/c60_5_1.jpg', 
'IMAGES': [], 
'MANUFACTURER': 'AquaDoctor', 
'COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN': 'Китай', 
'DESCRIPTION': 'Ударный, быстрорастворимый препарат содержащий 60% активного хлора. Поставляется в гранулированном виде. Предназначается для первичной (шоковой) обработки воды в бассейне. Уничтожает вирусы, бактерии, грибок, плесень.', 
'DESCRIPTION_FEATURE': ''},
{'CATEGORY_ID': 11, 
'IMAGE': 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2_heat_exchanger_1_2.jpg', 
'IMAGES': ['https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2_combine-2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2_heat_exchange_5_2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/e/l/elec_g2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/h/e/heat-exchanger-horizontal_s-2.png', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/f/i/file_42_2.jpg'], 
'Мощность': '30 кВт', 
'Дополнительно': '<ul class="bullet"><li>Корпус из нержавеющей стали BS 316L (EN 1.4432)</li><li>Трубки из титана</li><li>Максимальное рабочее давление до 4 Бар</li><li>Температурные ограничения первого контура теплообменника G2: 90 ℃</li><li>Полиамидная решетка</li><li>Камера с теплоизоляцией</li><li>Фитинги из латуни и специального полимерного состава</li><li>Высокая площадь теплопередачи</li><li>Возможность подключения аналоговых и цифровых комплектов контроля</li></ul>', 
'Комплектация': '<ul class="bullet"><li>Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30T</li><li>Латунные фитинги для первичного контура</li><li>Титановый карман для термостата</li><li>Обратный клапан</li><li>Фитинги соединения, заглушка, прокладка</li><li>Крепежная скоба</li><li>Инструкция</li></ul>', 
'Вес, кг': '2', 
'MANUFACTURER': 'Elecro', 
'Гарантия': '12 месяцев', 
'COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN': 'Великобритания', 
'DESCRIPTION': 'Теплообменник Elecro G2 для обогрева бассейнов. Имеет уникальный дизайн и надежную конструкцию из нержавеющей стали, титана, полимера и латуни. Обеспечивает непревзойденно большую площадь теплообмена с минимальными теплопотерями. Оптимальное решение для применения с газовыми или топливными бойлерами, солнечными панелями и другими тепловыми агрегатами.', 'DESCRIPTION_FEATURE': '<li>Мощность: 30 кВт</li><li>Трубки: титан</li><li>Корпус: нерж. сталь 316</li><li>Первичный контур: 1"</li><li>Вторичный контур: 1.5"</li>', 
'NAME': 'Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30 кВт (titanium)', 
'PRICE': '23\xa0381,00', 
'SKU': '6973'}
```

Как видно, у них разное количество полей

Пример csv, как должен выглядеть:

```
CATEGORY_ID;NAME;      PRICE; SKU; DESCRIPTION;   MANUFACTURER;  'Мощность'; ..;
   100;AquaDoctor C-60;1709,19;1551;Ударный, быстро..;'AquaDoctor';'30 кВт' ..    
    2;Теплообменник El;23081,00;6973;Теплообменник ..;'Elecro';           ;
```

;
Первая строка это названия заголовков, если появляется свойство которого нет в заголовке, то он добавляется туда.

Отсутствующие свойства у продуктов должны оставлять пустое место.

Comment: Как должен выглядеть этот CSV? Лучше такие данные хранить в JSON ...

Comment: @MaxU
1 строка названия столбцов,

Comment: Остальные строки, параметры продукта

Comment: Но нужно именно сохранить в csv

Comment: Приведите в вопросе CSV в том виде в котором вы хотите его получить на выходе.

Comment: @MaxU добавил пример CSV - файл

Comment: Интеренсно, если вам дадут ответ в котором будут троеточия вместо конкретного кода - это вас утсроит? Как будут выглядеть значения в столбце `IMAGES`? Складывается впечатление, что вы совершенно не заинтересованы в получении ответа. Советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: @MaxU я же не могу в табличном виде, представить все данные, они не уместятся, значения находятся выше, но ладно я попробую подставить некоторые значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с использованием модуля Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

data = [{'NAME': 'AquaDoctor C-60 50 кг. в гранулах', 
'PRICE': '17\xa0919,00', 
'STOCK_STATUS': False, 
'SKU': '1551', 
'CATEGORY_ID': 28, 
'IMAGE': 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/c/6/c60_5_1.jpg', 
'IMAGES': [], 
'MANUFACTURER': 'AquaDoctor', 
'COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN': 'Китай', 
'DESCRIPTION': 'Ударный, быстрорастворимый препарат содержащий 60% активного хлора. Поставляется в гранулированном виде. Предназначается для первичной (шоковой) обработки воды в бассейне. Уничтожает вирусы, бактерии, грибок, плесень.', 
'DESCRIPTION_FEATURE': ''},
{'CATEGORY_ID': 11, 
'IMAGE': 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2_heat_exchanger_1_2.jpg', 
'IMAGES': ['https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2_combine-2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2_heat_exchange_5_2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/e/l/elec_g2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/h/e/heat-exchanger-horizontal_s-2.png', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/f/i/file_42_2.jpg'], 
'Мощность': '30 кВт', 
'Дополнительно': '<ul class="bullet"><li>Корпус из нержавеющей стали BS 316L (EN 1.4432)</li><li>Трубки из титана</li><li>Максимальное рабочее давление до 4 Бар</li><li>Температурные ограничения первого контура теплообменника G2: 90 ?</li><li>Полиамидная решетка</li><li>Камера с теплоизоляцией</li><li>Фитинги из латуни и специального полимерного состава</li><li>Высокая площадь теплопередачи</li><li>Возможность подключения аналоговых и цифровых комплектов контроля</li></ul>', 
'Комплектация': '<ul class="bullet"><li>Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30T</li><li>Латунные фитинги для первичного контура</li><li>Титановый карман для термостата</li><li>Обратный клапан</li><li>Фитинги соединения, заглушка, прокладка</li><li>Крепежная скоба</li><li>Инструкция</li></ul>', 
'Вес, кг': '2', 
'MANUFACTURER': 'Elecro', 
'Гарантия': '12 месяцев', 
'COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN': 'Великобритания', 
'DESCRIPTION': 'Теплообменник Elecro G2 для обогрева бассейнов. Имеет уникальный дизайн и надежную конструкцию из нержавеющей стали, титана, полимера и латуни. Обеспечивает непревзойденно большую площадь теплообмена с минимальными теплопотерями. Оптимальное решение для применения с газовыми или топливными бойлерами, солнечными панелями и другими тепловыми агрегатами.', 'DESCRIPTION_FEATURE': '<li>Мощность: 30 кВт</li><li>Трубки: титан</li><li>Корпус: нерж. сталь 316</li><li>Первичный контур: 1"</li><li>Вторичный контур: 1.5"</li>', 
'NAME': 'Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30 кВт (titanium)', 
'PRICE': '23\xa0381,00', 
'SKU': '6973'}]

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(r'd:/temp/result.csv', index=False)
```

результат:

```
CATEGORY_ID,COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN,DESCRIPTION,DESCRIPTION_FEATURE,IMAGE,IMAGES,MANUFACTURER,NAME,PRICE,SKU,STOCK_STATUS,"Вес, кг",Гарантия,Дополнительно,Комплектация,Мощность
28,Китай,"Ударный, быстрорастворимый препарат содержащий 60% активного хлора. Поставляется в гранулированном виде. Предназначается для первичной (шоковой) обработки воды в бассейне. Уничтожает вирусы, бактерии, грибок, плесень.",,https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/c/6/c60_5_1.jpg,[],AquaDoctor,AquaDoctor C-60 50 кг. в гранулах,"17 919,00",1551,False,,,,,
11,Великобритания,"Теплообменник Elecro G2 для обогрева бассейнов. Имеет уникальный дизайн и надежную конструкцию из нержавеющей стали, титана, полимера и латуни. Обеспечивает непревзойденно большую площадь теплообмена с минимальными теплопотерями. Оптимальное решение для применения с газовыми или топливными бойлерами, солнечными панелями и другими тепловыми агрегатами.","<li>Мощность: 30 кВт</li><li>Трубки: титан</li><li>Корпус: нерж. сталь 316</li><li>Первичный контур: 1""</li><li>Вторичный контур: 1.5""</li>",https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2_heat_exchanger_1_2.jpg,"['https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2_combine-2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2_heat_exchange_5_2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/g/2/g2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/e/l/elec_g2.jpg', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/h/e/heat-exchanger-horizontal_s-2.png', 'https://aquapolis.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/f/i/file_42_2.jpg']",Elecro,Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30 кВт (titanium),"23 381,00",6973,,2,12 месяцев,"<ul class=""bullet""><li>Корпус из нержавеющей стали BS 316L (EN 1.4432)</li><li>Трубки из титана</li><li>Максимальное рабочее давление до 4 Бар</li><li>Температурные ограничения первого контура теплообменника G2: 90 ?</li><li>Полиамидная решетка</li><li>Камера с теплоизоляцией</li><li>Фитинги из латуни и специального полимерного состава</li><li>Высокая площадь теплопередачи</li><li>Возможность подключения аналоговых и цифровых комплектов контроля</li></ul>","<ul class=""bullet""><li>Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30T</li><li>Латунные фитинги для первичного контура</li><li>Титановый карман для термостата</li><li>Обратный клапан</li><li>Фитинги соединения, заглушка, прокладка</li><li>Крепежная скоба</li><li>Инструкция</li></ul>",30 кВт
```

Comment: Здравствуйте в итоговом файле, все русские названия имеют какую то левую кодировку, попробовал указать encoding='utf-8', не помогло

Comment: Пример 1 строки: CATEGORY_ID,COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN,DESCRIPTION,DESCRIPTION_FEATURE,IMAGE,IMAGES,MANUFACTURER,NAME,PRICE,SKU,STOCK_STATUS,Р”РѕРїРѕР»РЅРёС‚РµР»СЊРЅРѕ,РљРѕРјРїР»РµРєС‚Р°С†РёСЏ

Comment: Это вы открыли файл сохраненный в `UTF-8` в кодировке `CP-1251`. Можно явно задать кодировку: `pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(r'd:/temp/result.csv', index=False, encoding='cp1251')`

Comment: Мне как раз нужно сохранить в utf-8, но чтобы с латиницей все было норм.

Comment: Извините, это Excel тупит, открыл через VS Code с указанием кодировки, стало все норм

Comment: Pandas по умолчанию сохраняет как UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, вам нужен функционал [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) и [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter). Первый считывает данные в [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), при этом, если количество полей в заголовке больше, чем в данных, вместо данных он по умолчанию подставляет None. Ну а второй метод всю эту красоту записывает.

**UPDATE** *(после дополнительных пояснений автора вопроса)*

Похоже, что задача формально сводится к слиянию списка ключей в словарях. В таком случае решение может быть таким:

```
import pprint #нужно исключительно для красивого вывода

dict1 = {'NAME': 'AquaDoctor C-60 50 кг. в гранулах', 
'IMAGE': '1_2.jpg', 
'PRICE': '17\xa0919,00', 
'STOCK_STATUS': False, 
'SKU': '1551', 
'CATEGORY_ID': 28, 
'DESCRIPTION': 'blah',
'DESCRIPTION_FEATURE': ''}

dict2={'CATEGORY_ID': 11, 
'IMAGE': '1_2.jpg', 
'IMAGES': ['s-2.png', '42_2.jpg'], 
'Комплектация': 'Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30T', 
'Вес, кг': '2', 
'MANUFACTURER': 'Elecro', 
'Гарантия': '12 месяцев', 
'COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN': 'Великобритания', 
'DESCRIPTION': 'foo', 
'NAME': 'Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30 кВт (titanium)', 
'PRICE': '23\xa0381,00', 
'SKU': '6973'}

new1 = {**dict.fromkeys(dict1.keys(),''), **dict2}
new2 = {**dict.fromkeys(dict2.keys(),''), **dict1}
pprint.pprint(new1)
pprint.pprint(new2)
```

На выходе будем иметь:

```
{'CATEGORY_ID': 11,
 'COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN': 'Великобритания',
 'DESCRIPTION': 'foo',
 'DESCRIPTION_FEATURE': '',
 'IMAGE': '1_2.jpg',
 'IMAGES': ['s-2.png', '42_2.jpg'],
 'MANUFACTURER': 'Elecro',
 'NAME': 'Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30 кВт (titanium)',
 'PRICE': '23\xa0381,00',
 'SKU': '6973',
 'STOCK_STATUS': '',
 'Вес, кг': '2',
 'Гарантия': '12 месяцев',
 'Комплектация': 'Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30T'}
{'CATEGORY_ID': 28,
 'COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN': '',
 'DESCRIPTION': 'blah',
 'DESCRIPTION_FEATURE': '',
 'IMAGE': '1_2.jpg',
 'IMAGES': '',
 'MANUFACTURER': '',
 'NAME': 'AquaDoctor C-60 50 кг. в гранулах',
 'PRICE': '17\xa0919,00',
 'SKU': '1551',
 'STOCK_STATUS': False,
 'Вес, кг': '',
 'Гарантия': '',
 'Комплектация': ''}
```

Как видно, набор ключей у всех одинаковый, уникальные значения сохранены для каждого словаря, а отсутствующие значения ключей обозначены пустой строкой ''.

**UPDATE #2**
*Сохранение всего, что мы натворили в csv-файл:*

```
fieldnames = new1.keys()
with open('111.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(new1)
    writer.writerow(new2)
```

На выходе:

```
NAME,IMAGE,PRICE,STOCK_STATUS,SKU,CATEGORY_ID,DESCRIPTION,DESCRIPTION_FEATURE,IMAGES,Комплектация,"Вес, кг",MANUFACTURER,Гарантия,COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN

Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30 кВт (titanium),1_2.jpg,"23 381,00",,6973,11,foo,,"['s-2.png', '42_2.jpg']",Теплообменник Elecro G2 HE 30T,2,Elecro,12 месяцев,Великобритания

AquaDoctor C-60 50 кг. в гранулах,1_2.jpg,"17 919,00",False,1551,28,blah,,,,,,,
```

Comment: А как я узнаю fieldnames? При каждом добавлении продукта, проверять у него поля и если их добавлять в Header

Comment: @danilshik Я полагаю, что 1) считали основной csv - его заголовок сохранили в OrderedDict 2) считали новый csv - его заголовок добавили в сохраненный OrderedDict методом update 3) сохранили полученные данные в файл.

Comment: Я не использую данные из csv. Данные у меня представляют значения, которые я спарсил с сайта. И мне их нужно сохранить в csv-файл

Comment: Да, примерно так. Теперь как сохранить в csv файл? Точнее вопросы связаны, как сохранить правильно header(ключи)